# can I play a video from youtube with chewie?

Tags: flutter

I`m trying to create an app to play videos from firebase database using chewie. If I play an asset video it works fine, but if I try to get a youtube video from firebase it shows a white denying symbol, I tried a different source of video it works, but my goal is to access youtube videos. I used a real device, tried on both Android and IOS but nothing worked. Any lights on what could be a solution?

Comment: Check this issue https://github.com/brianegan/chewie/issues/268

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any package or way to view both Youtube videos and Normal Videos in a Single Video Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61681298/any-package-or-way-to-view-both-youtube-videos-and-normal-videos-in-a-single-vid)

Answer (score 0):

The chewie plugin has yet to have support for Youtube as tracked in this [thread](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/chewie/issues/268). The package can only play video stream URLs. Alternatives for this is to use other plugins like [youtube_player_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter) which has support for Youtube links. The other plugin [youtube_player_iframe](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_iframe) provides more granular API access.