# Any package or way to view both Youtube videos and Normal Videos in a Single Video Player

Tags: flutter, video-player

I have a page on which I am playing videos from both the links, these are:

- Youtube URLs
- Normal Video URLs like Vimeo etc

I have used this famous flutter package that is, [video_player](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/video_player), and also used a very useful package which wraps the **video_player** with all the inbuilt controls, which is, [chewie 0.9.10](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie#-installing-tab-)

Now the above one is capable of running the videos which are normal, and not from Youtube. For Youtube videos, there are packages available, these are: [youtube_player_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter) and [youtube_player](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player).

But the **Challenge here is, to find a workaround which plays both of the videos that is from NORMAL VIDEO URL and YOUTUBE URL without having any problem**.
I am searching for a way out, and found nothing till then. I hope I find some useful answers here, so that I can make use of it in my flutter application. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

[video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) or [chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie) can only network(with streaming url), assets or file videos.
So first we need a way to indentify if the **video URL** is from youtube.
Then we can use the [youtube_explode_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_explode_dart) to obtain the youtube video stream url, so the player can reproduce.

Below is a code snippet from one of my projects:

```
String convertUrlToId(String url, {bool trimWhitespaces = true}) {
  assert(url?.isNotEmpty ?? false, 'Url cannot be empty');
  String _url;
  if (!url.contains('http') && (url.length == 11)) return url;
  if (trimWhitespaces) {
    _url = url.trim();
  } else {
    _url = url;
  }

  for (final exp in [
    RegExp(r'^https:\/\/(?:www\.|m\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([_\-a-zA-Z0-9]{11}).*$'),
    RegExp(
        r'^https:\/\/(?:www\.|m\.)?youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\/embed\/([_\-a-zA-Z0-9]{11}).*$'),
    RegExp(r'^https:\/\/youtu\.be\/([_\-a-zA-Z0-9]{11}).*$')
  ]) {
    final Match match = exp.firstMatch(_url);
    if (match != null && match.groupCount >= 1) return match.group(1);
  }

  return null;
}
```

```
Future<String> _extractVideoUrl() async {
  if (%%IS_VIDEO_FROM_YOUTUBE%%) {
    final extractor = YoutubeExplode();
    final videoId = convertUrlToId(widget.videoUrl);
    final streamManifest = await extractor.videos.streamsClient.getManifest(videoId);
    final streamInfo = streamManifest.muxed.withHighestBitrate();
    extractor.close();
    return streamInfo.url.toString();
  }
  return null;
}
```

And then, finally.

```
_videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(%%URL_EXTRACTED%%)..initialize();
```

Comment: can I use the youtube_explode_dart library in an app that will be in both stores (app store and play store)?, I don't know if there is any legal problems with that.